# Name of thin metal tube / bar running across front and right of early RAV4 engine compartment

Tags: part-identification, rav4

I'm trying to figure out the name of the above described in my 1997 Toyota RAV4. It's not labeled in my Haynes manual. In the below pic it's the white line across the front between the labels 6, 7, 8, 10 and 12

[image]

Here's a close up photo of  it on the right hand side (from driver's point of view) passing the alternator and horn:

[image]

Comment: One of the air conditioning pipes?

Comment: Not sure, there's no mention of it anywhere in the section on air conditioning and cooling despite in being visible in several of the photos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the A/C refrigerant high pressure liquid line.